# Where is my bind address?

Tags: mysql

With `mysqld --verbose --help`, I got this cnf files

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
The following groups are read: mysqld server mysqld-10.0 mariadb mariadb-10.0 client-server
```

With netstat -tln

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:31416           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

I want to change my Local Address 127.0.1.:53 to 127.0.0.:3036.How to do this?

EDIT

```
cat ~/.my.cnf
cat: /home/milenko/.my.cnf: No such file or directory
```

IT DOES NOT FIND THIS CNF FILE AT ALL.

```
milenko@milenko-desktop:~$ cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

Should I add the port in this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your port in your my.cnf file.

```
port = 3306
```

**As per your edit:**

MariaDB is slightly different. Your config file is in this location:

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

And it's called *.cnf (something that's not usually my.cnf). For example, 50-server.cnf.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Don't put it in that file, edit in your mariadb-only config file. The one mentioned above.